# Using HTML forms input for python code and getting output back in HTML webpage

Tags: python, html, css, apache, http

I´ve been looking for answers and just lost the sight in all the different ones here.
I am bulding a tool, where you can enter a funding ID (included in papers) and a python code collects different papers from different websites and gives them a score in relevance.
My problem: I built a website with html/css and now I want to use the entered funding ID in one of the forms to pass it on to my python program. I know that i can use *action* in the form in my html to connect my html file with a different file. I read a lot of things about CGI and servers and Apache, etc. others talked about flask. **I just want to find a simple way to exchange information from my html file and my python code** and how can I display the information I got from my code in an HTML website?

Thank you!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}
.header {
  
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0C0040;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.text_header {
  margin-left: 160px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

.sub_header {
  color: #00BFFF;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #474e5d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #00BFFF;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.title{
  color: #0C0040
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;} 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <div class="text_header">
  <h1>Looking for more?</h1>
  <div class="sub_header">
  <p>find equally relevant papers from the same funder</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--- so far only the About Us page is linked --->
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="../AboutUs/aboutus.html">About Us</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="title"> <h2>Insert your funding ID here:</h2></div>

  <!--- this is the form where the input is put in--->
  <div class="input">
  <form name="search" action="../Python/example.py" method="post">
    <label for="input">enter in correct format:</label>
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  </div>
  
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING:** This is only for amusement purposes--do not use in production.

Sticking to the Python standard library, here's an example to get you started.

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


class WebServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        funding_id = bytes.decode(self.rfile.read(content_length)).split('input=')[1]
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(f'<html><head><title>Funding ID Form Submit</title></head><body><p><b>Funding ID:</b> {funding_id}</p></body></html>', "utf-8"))


ws = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), WebServer)
ws.serve_forever()
```

You will need to change the action attribute of your HTML `<form>` to `action="http://localhost:8080/"` to see this in action.

Similarly, you can serve normal page requests by implementing the `do_GET` method for the `WebServer` class.

As already stated, this is for amusement/learning purposes. If you're putting something into production, look into learning something like [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)